# What is the opposite of “simultaneously”?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What is the opposite of “simultaneously”? Either a single word or a short phrase would do.

> Add A, B, and C to the mix simultaneously or ????.

Also, if there are useful opposites, having both formal and informal versions would be helpful. And, if there is any opposite, does it entail any specific order in which A, B, and C are added?

Comment: I think  you are looking for "*not at the same time*" and "*respectively*",http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/respectively

Comment: I'd consider using [discretely](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discretely) in addition to the words suggested in the answers below

Comment: I think *separately* suits well here

Comment: You can't think of "one after the other"? You can't even think of "not simultaneously"? You can't even think of "thesaurus"? You can't even think of dropping that bit completely as it is utterly unnecessary? If you are looking to express something that you cannot express, and that something does not need to be expressed in the first place, then your search is over right there. Just "Add A, B, and C to the mix." Period.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, wow, you seem like a really nice person.

Answer (score 17):

A single apt word would be *sequentially*, one following another. In

> Add A, B, and C **sequentially**

the implication is add A, then B, and finally C.

If you don't know anything about the order:

> Add A, B, and C **sequentially** in no particular order.

Answer (score 11):

You could consider using [***one by one***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/one-after-another) which means:

> first one, then the next, then the next etc, ***separately***

[Macmillan Online Dictionary]

Oxford Learner's Dictionary defines *one by one*:

> separately and ***in order***: *I went through the items on the list one by one*.

*Separately in order* or *individually in order* is a good candidate, too.

Comment: Thanks. That's a helpful list. I wonder, though, if things could be added at the same time but separately. For example, two things that are often united, such as a nut an a bolt, are added, say, to a lubricant can, uncoupled, and so separately, but at the same time.

Answer (score 10):

I think **consecutively** could fit:

> Consecutive periods of time or events happen **one after the other** without interruption

([Collins Learner's Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american-cobuild-learners/consecutive))

Or **successively**:

> Successive means happening or existing **one after another** without a break.

[Collins Learner's Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american-cobuild-learners/successive)

Alternatively, how about **one after the other**:

> first one person or thing and then another, followed by more

([TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/one+after+the+other))

Answer (score 7):

Without regard for order,

> **asynchronously**, *adv.*
>   In an asynchronous manner; at differing times.

([OED Online](http://oed.com/))

With regard for order,

> Add A, B, and C asynchronously, in order.

Informally, this might be expressed as

> Add A, B, and C at differing times, in order.

Comment: Caveat: within CS/programming the word asynchronous is often used as a synonym of parallel, meaning that tasks are executed simultaneously (i.e. the opposite of the requested meaning).

Comment: @Anton, thanks for the suggestion. It's a common misunderstanding of the use of the term in CS, but I'm not going to make a caveat for a misuse and misconception of the term. You might want to re-examine your understanding of the use in CS: see [asynchronous in Technology](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/asynchronous?s=t).

Comment: Oh I'm not saying it's correct, I'm just saying it's happening and will potentially confuse people.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for this word:

[Singly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/singly) – 2nd definition

> 2. One at a time; as single units.

An example sentence given is:

> They traveled in pairs or **singly**, and headed off to separate
>   destinations in Europe, Asia, and Africa.

Or you can choose [**One at a time**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/one+at+a+time)

> In single file; "the prisoners came out one by one"